# ESP8266 - client socket is getting closed after calling method readBytes

Tags: java, sockets, c++11, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to send a message from my pc to the board, but the problem is I keep losing connection before I decide to send a message.

This is code from which I'm sending the message. I create a socket, connect to the board, and then wait for inputs from the Scanner object. When I get some input I send a message to the board.

CLIENT

```
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.4.1",3000));
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String message = DataProtocol.sendMessageFormat("KLASA","METHOD","FILIP CACIC");
    String message1 = DataProtocol.sendMessageFormat("KLASA","METHOD","FILIP CACIC");
    message = message1 + message;
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

    String line;
    while(!(line = in.nextLine()).equals("EXIT")){
        outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
    }
```

This is code that is `recv.message`.

SERVER

```
void CommunicationProcessor::readFromStream(WiFiClient* wifiClient){
CLIENT_ACTIVE = true;

while(CLIENT_ACTIVE){
    Serial.println(wifiClient->connected()); -> returns 1
    int bytesRead = wifiClient->readBytes(buffer,1024); -> returns 0
    Serial.println(wifiClient->connected()); -> returns 0
    dataManager.appendData(bufferReader.getDataReaded(buffer,bytesRead));

    if (checkIfEndLine(bytesRead)){
        handleDataRecv();
        dataManager.clearBuffer();
    }
}
Serial.println("CLIENT QUIT");
```

}

Before method `readBytes`, I call method `connected()` and it returns `1`. So everything is fine. 
Method readBytes returns `0`, because I did not yet send any message.
After that, I call `connected()` one more time and this time it returns `0`.

Now if I remove this Scanner object and loop from code and send a message immediately, a server will recv. message.

```
    Socket socket = new Socket();
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.4.1",3000));
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String message = DataProtocol.sendMessageFormat("KLASA","METHOD","FILIP CACIC");
    String message1 = DataProtocol.sendMessageFormat("KLASA","METHOD","FILIP CACIC");
    message = message1 + message;
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
```

My questions are why is connection closed after I call method `readBytes`?

EDIT

I just tested with this code and connection still get lost.
Line "Client alive" only gets printed one time.

SERVER

```
 void loop(){
   delay(1000);
   if (client){
     Serial.println("Client alive");
     Serial.println(client.connected());
   }else{
     client = server.available();
     if (client){
       Serial.println(client.connected());
   }
```

}
}

EDIT 2

I found the problem. I was using board as WIFI-ACCESS POINT, but when I connected board to my router and my pc, everything works fine.
So now my questions is why am I losing connection when board is configured as ACCESS-POINT?

EDIT 3

I found what was causing the problem. I had problem with connecting to wifi access point so i called method WIFI.persistent(false) and that was causing Broken Pipe exception (stream closed) in java.

Comment: what is the size of the server buffer. is it at least 1024 bytes? you push too much data with the while loop in client

Comment: yes,buffer size is 1024

Comment: how do you power it?

Comment: through pc, but i found the problem. I had some problems with wifi and i called method WiFi.persistent(false) and that was causing the connection lost